# Finding specific overlapping pattern using Python

Tags: python, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract out all instances of the VCV (vowel consonant vowel) pattern in a word using regex. This should also include the start and end, which could be CV when at the start or VC when at the end.

Given the word "bookeeping" as an input, the expected output would be:

```
boo, ookee, eepi, ing
```

My current attempt using the regex library for overlapping patterns looks like:

```
import regex as re

word = "bookeeping"
print(re.findall(r'[aeiouy]+?[bcdfghkjlmnpqrstvwxz]+[aeiouy]+', word, overlapped=True))
```

with the (incorrect) output:

```
['ookkee', 'okkee', 'eepi', 'epi']
```

'okkee' is not valid and it does not grab the start or end. How do I force it to exclude words that do not include all preceding matches?

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing everything, it wasn't clear at all. Also a small snippet to run the regex would help a lot to speed up everything.

Comment: I do not see the vowel consonant vowel pattern in your expected output?

Comment: `boo` <-- how is this match of a vowel-consonant-vowel pattern? Same goes for `ing`.

Comment: zwer and pkpkpk, I did not have enough information in the description of the question; I also needed to include the start and end of words. That resuts in a CV when at the start and a VC when at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your expected output that vowels are optional in the vowel-consonant-vowel pattern you're looking for, in which case the following will do:

```
import re
pos = 0
while True:
    match = re.search(r'[aeiouy]*[bcdfghkjlmnpqrstvwxz]+([aeiouy]*)', 'bookeeping'[pos:])
    if not match:
        break
    print(match.group(0))
    pos += match.start(1)
```

This outputs:

```
boo
ookee
eepi
ing
```

Comment: This works for all cases that I need it to. Thank you. I am not sure how the logic works, however. What is pos += match.start(1) doing?

Comment: [`match.start(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) returns the position of the start of the substring captured by the first group in the regex. And by incrementing `pos` by that much, we can skip the first vowels and consonants in the last match for our next iteration.